# what is " touch table teach-ins"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a sentence in an advertisement of a zoo:

> Then feel what it is like to stroke a crocodile or leopard at one of our **regular touch table teach-ins**.

I have looked up the word **teach-in** in OALD and its meaning seems to have no relevance to the zoo:

> An informal lecture and discussion or series of lectures on a subject of public interest.

I also looked up this word on the Internet but there is no result which is related to zoos. So what does **touch table tech-ins** mean?

Comment: How about an informal talk taking place at a table where participants can touch animals?

Comment: "touch table" might refer to table-sized tablet ("touch screen") devices, eg https://www.spintouch.com/interactive-solutions/hardware/mozayo/ - "The interactive touch table people have been waiting for ". If so, then a "touch table teach-in" would be an informal lecture taking place around one of these devices.

Comment: I would expect a *touch table* in the education section of a zoo to mean somewhere children can handle animal (and perhaps habitat) artefacts, such as feathers, pelts, etc. It might extend to small docile animals (anything from guinea pigs to snakes) but I'd expect different wording to be used then. So my *guess* is that it's crocodile skin and leopard fur.

Comment: ... Sometimes there's a table with compartments into which you can reach through flaps without being able to see what's in there, allowing you to guess what you've just touched.

Comment: That seems to describe a fairly informal lecture - "teach-in" - centred around a surface with creatures crawling around on it - "touch table".

That would perfectly fit the informal lecture going on at a crocodile farm where I was encouraged to hold a nine-inch baby and even put my finger in its mouth!